# Why is str not a subclass of collections.abc.ByteString?

Tags: python, abstract-class, abc

When having a look at the types `str` and `bytes` in Python, it turns out they are very similiar. The only differences wrt. their attributes are:

```
>>> set(dir(bytes)) - set(dir(str))
{'hex', 'fromhex', 'decode'}
>>> set(dir(str)) - set(dir(bytes))
{'isidentifier', 'encode', 'isdecimal', 'isnumeric', 'casefold', 'format', 'isprintable', 'format_map'}
```

Checking the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.ByteString), I figured that these differences should not be relevant for their relation to the abstract base class `collections.abc.ByteString`. However, `bytes` is regarded a subclass while `str` is not:

```
>>> issubclass(bytes, collections.abc.ByteString)
True
>>> issubclass(str, collections.abc.ByteString)
False
```

While the observed behaviour is useful to discern these types, I do not understand why Python behaves that way. In my understanding of Python's duck typing concept, both `str` and `bytes` should be regarded as subclasses, as long as they bring the relevant attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `str` isn't a string of bytes. `ByteString`'s meaning isn't encompassed by its methods, and `str` does not fit the meaning of `ByteString`. (The ABC mostly exists as a way to bundle `bytes` and `bytearray` for `isinstance` checks, hence the "This unifies bytes and bytearray." in its docstring.)

You might wonder why `issubclass` doesn't automatically consider `str` a `ByteString` subclass anyway based on its methods. Unless an ABC specifically implements [`__subclasshook__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__) to check for methods, `issubclass` will not automatically consider a class a subclass of an ABC based on the presence of any particular methods. `bytes` and `bytearray` are subclasses of `ByteString` because they are specifically [`register`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register)ed as subclasses.

Comment: Just had a look at the `_collections_abc.py` source: While many of the (simpler) ABCs implement `__subclasshook__` to check for existing methods, `ByteString` does not and only registers `bytes` and `bytearray`.

Answer (score 0):

From a practical point of view, `str` and `bytes` cannot be substituted for each other, so there wouldn't be any use making them subclasses of anything more specific than `Iterable` or `Hashable` or `Sized`...

If you want to use them interchangeably, there's probably a bug in the program.